# Warnings about unused variables in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I recently started Erlang, and I notice I constantly get "Warning: variable X is unused" while compiling.  For example, take the following function, which finds the maximum element in a list:

```
    max([Head|Tail]) ->
       max(Head,Tail).

    max(Element,[Head | Tail]) when Element < Head ->
       max(Head,Tail);
    max(Element,[Head | Tail]) ->
       max(Element, Tail);
    max(Element,[]) ->
       Element.
```

The compiler warns me that in the 3rd case of the function, Head is unused.  How can the function be written without Head?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should suppress the warning without being confusing:

```
max(Element,[_Head | Tail]) ->
   max(Element, Tail);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you name a variable `_` instead of `Name` (e.g. `_` instead of `Head`) the variable will not be bound, and you will not get a warning.

If you name a variable `_Name` instead of `Name` (e.g. `_Head` instead of `Head`) the variable *will* be bound, but you will still not get a warning. Referencing a variable beginning with `_` in the code is considered *very* bad practice.

It is recommended to keep the name of the variable to improve the readability of the code (e.g. it is easier to guess what `_Head` was intended for than just `_`).

Comment: Your last two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: I suspect "using" in this case means "use teh value bound to" rather than "use the _Name construct".

Comment: With "using a variable" I mean referencing it in code, and "using a variable name" I mean naming it something.

Answer (score 6):

```
    max([Head|Tail]) ->
       max(Head,Tail).

    max(Element,[Head | Tail]) when Element < Head ->
       max(Head,Tail);
    max(Element,[_| Tail]) ->
       max(Element, Tail);
    max(Element,[]) ->
       Element.
```

Should do the trick. The reason being that replacing 'Head' with '_' is syntax for saying that a parameter will be placed there, but I don't need it.